# How to let a vertical layout group stretch with components? - Unity - C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a chat system where you can add friends, I made a vertical layout group that will contain all of the search results but when the search results go out of the border of the vertical layout group, the vertical layout group will just stay the same size. Now I cant add a scroll rect that can scroll through the vertical layout group. This is very annoying and I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `Scroll View` UI object for shortcut.

Add `Vertical Layout Group` with the `Content` object. Instantiate objects as `Content`'s child which are scrollable.

[image]

This also can be created manually. Explore the child objects and theirs components of `Scroll View` object.