# How to make a custom List view of Videos in Unity3D taking video links from APIs?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I am working on a Unity Project, 
and I am trying to Load and Run Videos at runtime.

All the video links are coming from the API at runtime.
Unity doesn't have a `ListView` or a `Collection View` like (Android or iOS) to render Video with controls (play-pause-stop)?

How can we do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> Unity doesn't have a ListView or a Collection View Like (Android or
>   iOS) to render Video with controls (play-pause-stop)?

Unity has [`ListView`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Experimental.UIElements.ListView.html) which is new and still in experiment mode in version *2018.2*.

You don't even need that. You can use the `ScrollView` in addition with the `Vertical Layout Group` to accomplish what you need. It should look like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39982009/3785314). A basic understanding of how to create UI objects is required. See [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/user-interface-ui).

As for playing video, you need to use the `RawImage` component. They should be placed under the "Content" Object of the `ScrollView`. You only need one `VideoPlayer` component in the scene and can use code to tell it which `RawImage` to play video on and change the video url.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41154599/3785314) post for how to play video on a `RawImage` component.